# I've received an HTTP POST from an android app in my jsp server, how do I pass that data into a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, android, jsp

I have this in my jsp file:

```
<form name='form1'>
<input type='hidden' name=NAME value=<%=request.getParameter("name")%> />
</form>
```

It works, I get the "name" when I submit it through android, but then it reverts back to null. How do I get it to stay "name"?

Also, I put the request.getParameter in a form to be able to access the value in my js code using 'document.form1.NAME.value'

To further clarify:
When I print what "request.getParameter" gives me in the server console, I get the value I'm sending through a submit button on my Android app, then two nulls.

So I get:

actual value

null

null

It seems like jsp is running three times?? and setting request.getParameter back to null?

Workflow:

I have an android app that, when you click the submit button, sends whatever string the user entered (in a text box on the app) to a Tomcat server that has a jsp file on it.

My jsp file then reads the request.

My javascript is what needs string (it takes the string, modifies it, and then displays an alert with the modified string).

*Could it be since I'm opening up the jsp file AFTER I send my requests, that it can't find the previous requests?*

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("Tomcat server with my.jsp");

        EditText nameBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        String n = nameBox.getText().toString();

        try
        {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", n));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        }

        catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
        }

        String url = "The same server and same.jsp file";
        Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        webIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(webIntent);
```

Comment: What research have you undertaken yourself in this matter?

Comment: I've tried a lot of different ways, including passing the data through parameters in the js function (function(${httppostrequestparameter})). I've seen people that use Ajax, but I'm trying not to do that since I'm only passing three strings.

Comment: After you submit it's a *new request*, and won't have the parameters from a *previous request*.

Comment: Can you explain your workflow a bit? Is the jsp submitting to itself? What's the flow? Is the Javascript doing any redirects?

Comment: I don't know why my server's receiving three requests though...could it be just something about how jsp loads? Checking my android code again now, but I think I only submit one request..

Comment: and sorry editing my original post now, will explain workflow better

Comment: That is not sufficient, because if that was the actual workflow, there'd be no form submit, and the value wouldn't be null, and setting it directly as a JS variable would work fine (once it was properly JS-escaped).

Comment: This initial submit.. is it being done from a web page loaded in a WebView in your app? Is it the same JSP? Is the sumbit button submitting an HTML form or is it native Android code?

Comment: Yes, you're making two different HTTP requests. `webIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));` would be making a new request that wouldn't submit the `name` post parameter.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!! I took that out and the server only received on request!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with proper quotes around:

```
<form name='form1'>
  <input type='hidden' name='NAME' value='<%= request.getParameter("name") %>' />
</form>
```

Try setting the script variable directly as

```
var name = '<%= request.getParameter ("name") %>';
```

***EDIT** :*

Yes, you're making two different HTTP requests. webIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url)); would be making a new request that wouldn't submit the name post parameter. What you need is to somehow render the response collected before in your app.

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Since, this is the request where you set your name-value pairs, this would have the JavaScript variable set.

Comment: Still gives me null, but thanks for the heads up about the quotes.

Comment: The quotes only matter if there's a space in the parameter.